# juju bootstrap on a private openstack cloud fails

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I have followed the instructions on using juju with a private Openstack cloud https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/howto-privatecloud
My juju client is a ubuntu vm in the same openstack cloud.
After following all the instructions at the command

```
juju bootstrap igestack osicontroller --config network=024dbb2d-fb3e-43d2-8b0f-b93fe6162516 --config image-metadata-url=http://192.168.170.45:80/swift/v1/simplestreams/images
--debug --show-log
```

I get:

```
08:48:46 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:63 running juju [2.0.1 gc go1.6.2]
08:48:46 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:64   args: []string{"juju", "bootstrap", "igestack", "--config", "network=024dbb2d-fb3e-43d2-8b0f-b93fe6162516", "--config", "image-metadata-url=http://192.168.170.45:80/swift/v1/simplestreams/images", "--debug", "--show-log"}
08:48:46 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:834 provider attrs: map[use-floating-ip:false use-default-secgroup:false network:024dbb2d-fb3e-43d2-8b0f-b93fe6162516]
08:48:49 INFO  cmd cmd.go:141 Adding contents of "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys
08:48:49 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:890 preparing controller with config: map[apt-http-proxy: use-default-secgroup:false agent-stream:released name:controller http-proxy: disable-network-management:false default-series:xenial ftp-proxy: https-proxy: apt-https-proxy: image-metadata-url:http://192.168.170.45:80/swift/v1/simplestreams/images test-mode:false uuid:cdf7e9d1-4daa-4c83-8262-4d7c915c743a agent-metadata-url: automatically-retry-hooks:true apt-ftp-proxy: transmit-vendor-metrics:true use-floating-ip:false apt-mirror: proxy-ssh:false enable-os-refresh-update:true ssl-hostname-verification:true network:024dbb2d-fb3e-43d2-8b0f-b93fe6162516 development:false no-proxy: resource-tags: logforward-enabled:false authorized-keys:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDdZduAUdZEh4Yv+JSXD9mMsVDdXCDJFFMNq3/7nfmFYctu0731ffXtqdae7jSycfJ5aD/n8JaE5WZ9PWraps3cQjg0T4nLBkhVBl8u2e/VKubCDQR2OYl/w6GCpVzSSctgwAmXeKkBinv1Mmur+sTTe9C8kSu/WxFd5MbgyU6Qs5j1oHoxjWB6v5z99g8m/CzNarHvYRGGVxAihhBwatb4IjW0/e3zpthL9CKjxvcN3tu5TEbk8pkQVVO+kQSrCovJ+vT4k3awfrNEt9hW6pYBM2rnCBgmARbhvoTvhEsUVokIrtZzGTepozZ/h3e2fdO0kS91VIyB9otHgwTJSHhl juju-client-key
 image-stream:released logging-config: type:openstack enable-os-upgrade:true ignore-machine-addresses:false provisioner-harvest-mode:destroyed firewall-mode:instance]
08:48:49 INFO  juju.provider.openstack provider.go:76 opening model "controller"
08:48:49 INFO  cmd cmd.go:129 Creating Juju controller "igestack-RegionOne" on igestack/RegionOne
08:48:50 INFO  juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:507 combined bootstrap constraints: 
08:48:50 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:185 model "controller" supports service/machine networks: false
08:48:50 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:187 network management by juju enabled: true
08:48:50 INFO  cmd cmd.go:141 Loading image metadata
08:48:50 DEBUG juju.environs imagemetadata.go:112 obtained image datasource "image-metadata-url"
08:48:50 DEBUG juju.environs imagemetadata.go:112 obtained image datasource "keystone catalog"
08:48:50 DEBUG juju.environs imagemetadata.go:112 obtained image datasource "default cloud images"
08:48:50 DEBUG juju.environs imagemetadata.go:112 obtained image datasource "default ubuntu cloud images"
08:48:50 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:557 constraints for image metadata lookup &{{{RegionOne http://192.168.170.46:5000/v2.0/} [win2012hvr2 win2012r2 win81 win10 genericlinux raring utopic xenial yakkety win2016nano win8 saucy trusty win2012 vivid wily win7 win2012hv win2016 centos7 zesty precise quantal win2008r2] [amd64 i386 armhf arm64 ppc64el s390x] released}}
08:48:50 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:569 found 1 image metadata in image-metadata-url
08:48:50 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:569 found 1 image metadata in keystone catalog
08:48:51 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:569 found 0 image metadata in default cloud images
08:48:51 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:454 skipping index "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/index.sjson" because of missing information: index file has no data for cloud {RegionOne http://192.168.170.46:5000/v2.0/} not found
08:48:51 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:565 ignoring image metadata in default ubuntu cloud images: index file has no data for cloud {RegionOne http://192.168.170.46:5000/v2.0/} not found
08:48:51 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:573 found 2 image metadata from all image data sources
08:48:52 INFO  cmd cmd.go:129 Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.0.1 for amd64
08:48:52 INFO  juju.environs.bootstrap tools.go:72 looking for bootstrap agent binaries: version=2.0.1
08:48:52 INFO  juju.environs.tools tools.go:101 finding agent binaries in stream "released"
08:48:52 INFO  juju.environs.tools tools.go:103 reading agent binaries with major.minor version 2.0
08:48:52 INFO  juju.environs.tools tools.go:111 filtering agent binaries by version: 2.0.1
08:48:52 INFO  juju.environs.tools tools.go:117 filtering agent binaries by architecture: amd64
08:48:52 DEBUG juju.environs.tools urls.go:109 trying datasource "keystone catalog"
08:48:52 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:680 using default candidate for content id "com.ubuntu.juju:released:tools" are {20161007 mirrors:1.0 content-download streams/v1/cpc-mirrors.sjson []}
08:48:53 INFO  juju.environs.bootstrap tools.go:74 found 16 packaged agent binaries
08:48:53 INFO  cmd cmd.go:141 Starting new instance for initial controller
Launching controller instance(s) on igestack/RegionOne...
08:48:54 INFO  juju.provider.common destroy.go:20 destroying model "controller"
08:48:54 INFO  juju.provider.common destroy.go:31 destroying instances
08:48:54 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:1021 error cleaning up: destroying controller model: destroying instances: failed to get list of server details
caused by: failed unmarshaling the response body: {"servers": [{"OS-EXT-STS:task_state": null, "addresses": {"internal": [{"OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:46:8c:b1", "version": 4, "addr": "10.5.5.9", "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed"}, {"OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:46:8c:b1", "version": 4, "addr": "192.107.88.60", "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "floating"}]}, "links": [{"href": "http://192.168.170.40:8774/v2.1/769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a/servers/04b98237-c057-4072-bf9f-94155f1101f7", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://192.168.170.40:8774/769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a/servers/04b98237-c057-4072-bf9f-94155f1101f7", "rel": "bookmark"}], "image": "", "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "active", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name": "instance-00000006", "OS-SRV-USG:launched_at": "2016-11-29T20:46:22.000000", "flavor": {"id": "9d4b661c-a2bb-442a-846d-06a1b6bc98e6", "links": [{"href": "http://192.168.170.40:8774/769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a/flavors/9d4b661c-a2bb-442a-846d-06a1b6bc98e6", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "id": "04b98237-c057-4072-bf9f-94155f1101f7", "security_groups": [{"name": "default"}], "user_id": "ff5fd8ccec9841889e7f3f509dec9523", "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "AUTO", "accessIPv4": "", "accessIPv6": "", "progress": 0, "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 1, "OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone": "nova", "metadata": {}, "status": "ACTIVE", "updated": "2016-12-01T09:39:32Z", "hostId": "f18e0f79dd4f137d08eaa37b3afa107978419d1260b59f88ab17a7b9", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "osigest1x12", "OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at": null, "key_name": "mykey", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname": "osigest1x12.maas", "name": "juju-master", "created": "2016-11-29T20:44:30Z", "tenant_id": "769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a", "os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached": [{"id": "2fc47f2d-3bad-4a2f-bb06-aa37773ca83c"}], "config_drive": ""}]}
caused by: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type nova.jsonEntity
08:48:54 ERROR cmd supercommand.go:458 failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance: failed to get list of server details
caused by: failed unmarshaling the response body: {"servers": [{"OS-EXT-STS:task_state": null, "addresses": {"internal": [{"OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:46:8c:b1", "version": 4, "addr": "10.5.5.9", "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed"}, {"OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:46:8c:b1", "version": 4, "addr": "192.107.88.60", "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "floating"}]}, "links": [{"href": "http://192.168.170.40:8774/v2.1/769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a/servers/04b98237-c057-4072-bf9f-94155f1101f7", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://192.168.170.40:8774/769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a/servers/04b98237-c057-4072-bf9f-94155f1101f7", "rel": "bookmark"}], "image": "", "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "active", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name": "instance-00000006", "OS-SRV-USG:launched_at": "2016-11-29T20:46:22.000000", "flavor": {"id": "9d4b661c-a2bb-442a-846d-06a1b6bc98e6", "links": [{"href": "http://192.168.170.40:8774/769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a/flavors/9d4b661c-a2bb-442a-846d-06a1b6bc98e6", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "id": "04b98237-c057-4072-bf9f-94155f1101f7", "security_groups": [{"name": "default"}], "user_id": "ff5fd8ccec9841889e7f3f509dec9523", "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "AUTO", "accessIPv4": "", "accessIPv6": "", "progress": 0, "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 1, "OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone": "nova", "metadata": {}, "status": "ACTIVE", "updated": "2016-12-01T09:39:32Z", "hostId": "f18e0f79dd4f137d08eaa37b3afa107978419d1260b59f88ab17a7b9", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "osigest1x12", "OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at": null, "key_name": "mykey", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname": "osigest1x12.maas", "name": "juju-master", "created": "2016-11-29T20:44:30Z", "tenant_id": "769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a", "os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached": [{"id": "2fc47f2d-3bad-4a2f-bb06-aa37773ca83c"}], "config_drive": ""}]}
caused by: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type nova.jsonEntity
08:48:54 DEBUG cmd supercommand.go:459 (error details: [{github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/commands/bootstrap.go:556: failed to bootstrap model} {github.com/juju/juju/provider/common/bootstrap.go:47: } {github.com/juju/juju/provider/common/bootstrap.go:178: cannot start bootstrap instance} {failed to get list of server details
caused by: failed unmarshaling the response body: {"servers": [{"OS-EXT-STS:task_state": null, "addresses": {"internal": [{"OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:46:8c:b1", "version": 4, "addr": "10.5.5.9", "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed"}, {"OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:46:8c:b1", "version": 4, "addr": "192.107.88.60", "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "floating"}]}, "links": [{"href": "http://192.168.170.40:8774/v2.1/769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a/servers/04b98237-c057-4072-bf9f-94155f1101f7", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "http://192.168.170.40:8774/769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a/servers/04b98237-c057-4072-bf9f-94155f1101f7", "rel": "bookmark"}], "image": "", "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "active", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name": "instance-00000006", "OS-SRV-USG:launched_at": "2016-11-29T20:46:22.000000", "flavor": {"id": "9d4b661c-a2bb-442a-846d-06a1b6bc98e6", "links": [{"href": "http://192.168.170.40:8774/769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a/flavors/9d4b661c-a2bb-442a-846d-06a1b6bc98e6", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "id": "04b98237-c057-4072-bf9f-94155f1101f7", "security_groups": [{"name": "default"}], "user_id": "ff5fd8ccec9841889e7f3f509dec9523", "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "AUTO", "accessIPv4": "", "accessIPv6": "", "progress": 0, "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 1, "OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone": "nova", "metadata": {}, "status": "ACTIVE", "updated": "2016-12-01T09:39:32Z", "hostId": "f18e0f79dd4f137d08eaa37b3afa107978419d1260b59f88ab17a7b9", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "osigest1x12", "OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at": null, "key_name": "mykey", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname": "osigest1x12.maas", "name": "juju-master", "created": "2016-11-29T20:44:30Z", "tenant_id": "769274dc9e79401c9f48a4efd982199a", "os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached": [{"id": "2fc47f2d-3bad-4a2f-bb06-aa37773ca83c"}], "config_drive": ""}]}
caused by: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type nova.jsonEntity}])
```

Could you please let me know what is wrong?
Thanks!

This is the content of http://192.168.170.45/swift/v1/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index.json :

```
{
    "index": {
        "com.ubuntu.cloud:custom": {
            "updated": "Mon, 12 Dec 2016 13:20:14 +0000",
            "format": "products:1.0",
            "datatype": "image-ids",
            "cloudname": "custom",
            "clouds": [
                {
                    "region": "RegionOne",
                    "endpoint": "http://192.168.170.46:5000/v2.0/"
                }
            ],
            "path": "streams/v1/com.ubuntu.cloud-released-imagemetadata.json",
            "products": [
                "com.ubuntu.cloud:server:16.04:amd64"
            ]
        }
    },
    "updated": "Mon, 12 Dec 2016 13:20:14 +0000",
    "format": "index:1.0"
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the contents of http://192.168.170.45:80/swift/v1/simplestreams/images/streams/v1/index.json

Comment: Is this your keystone IP 192.168.170.46?

Comment: Yes the keystone IP is 192.168.170.46 @Junaid

Comment: @Angelinux, would you please post the solution as answer then roll back the question edit. Ask Ubuntu is Q&A site (not a forum). see how it works in this [about].

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved by creating a new juju client and then following instructions literally.

There is no need to create a custom cloud inside juju, it is as simple as launching

```
juju bootstrap openstack
```

as written in the [juju charms documentation here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/howto-privatecloud)

Comment: **LQ reviewers:** Answer OK, close question instead.

Comment: Answer seems fine indeed, and no need to close the question imho